# How to host a .net core web app in linux?

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

is it possible to host .net core web app and possibly keep running it as background process in linux (RHEL)  , without IIS.

Comment: Yes, you can. Start reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: There are docs specifically for hosting on Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0